# Why can I not import a module (Batman) in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, import, module, jupyter-notebook, anaconda3

I'm trying to import a module (batman, for model transits) in jupyter notebook, but its telling me file not found. However when I use the anaconda terminal it imports without issues

[image: This is the error I get from Jupyter Notebook]
I've tried reinstalling the package, and I've tried to find a kernel in which it works, but I'm not sure how to go about that

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if the module installed properly by running this:

```
python -c 'import batman; batman.test()'
```

the batman module also seems to have some issues when installing on windows.
Read this github if you're on windows https://github.com/lkreidberg/batman/issues/26

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue when I use Jupyter in an Anaconda environment. Jupyter Notebook doesn't use the same kernel as Anaconda and I had to specify it manually.

What you can do is comparing the Python version on your Anaconda environment by running this command in your shell:

```
python --version
```

And in your Notebook :

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

Are the versions different ? If so, you must add your Anaconda kernel to your Notebook :

```
ipython kernel install --name "local-anaconda-env" --user
```

Then select it in your Notebook.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue in VSC. What I did is that first I moved the folder(In your case batman) to where VSC had been installed on my laptop. Then I changed the default directory to where VSC was installed on my laptop by running the following code in VSC.

```
import os
os.chdir("The path where VSC is installed")
```

Also If you could try to do the code in a python file instead of jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0):

In a cell within your notebook run the following:

```py
%pip install batman-package
```

Based on [here](https://lweb.cfa.harvard.edu/%7Elkreidberg/batman/installation.html).
And the use of modern `pip install` magic to handle installing to correct enviornment from inside a notebook, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez).

---

For others, hitting here and not seeing what they want/expect.
Above is for [batman:
Bad-Ass Transit Model cAlculatioN](https://lweb.cfa.harvard.edu/%7Elkreidberg/batman/). Associated [Github Repo is here](https://github.com/lkreidberg/batman), and [Python Package Index page](https://pypi.org/project/batman-package/).

This is a poor name for a package as at least three developers have claimed this. Also see:

- [Anaconda install for Batman at conda-forgeBayesian Analysis Tool for Modelling and uncertAinty quaNtification](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/batman)
- [BATMAN: A Python deployment toolbelt -Batman 0.7.0 at the Python Package Index](https://pypi.org/project/Batman/)

Maybe those links will help you.